# Syntax error drivingdistance

Tags: postgis, sql, pgrouting, query

I am new in sql and i am trying to get that works a subquery with pgr_drivingdistance and pgr_pointsaspolygon but i get the next error:

> subqueries in FROM must to have an alias,for example, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo.But in the code below the alias is di

Here is the code:

```
SELECT 1 as result,* FROM  pgr_pointsaspolygon('SELECT id, ST_X(the_geom) AS x, ST_Y(the_geom) AS y FROM ( 
     SELECT id,seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost, the_geom FROM pgr_drivingdistance(
       ''''SELECT id, source, target, time_4 as cost FROM jaen'''',
          1, 15, false, false
      )as di
      JOIN jaen_vertices_pgr pt
      ON di.id1 = pt.id)');
```

Comment: Isn't the problem that pgr_pointsapolyon returns a geometry, so you can't join it on id as you are? You should be able to run something like:, `SELECT * 
   FROM  pgr_pointsaspolygon('SELECT id, ST_X(the_geom) AS x, ST_Y(the_geom) AS y 
       FROM ( 
           SELECT id, seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost, the_geom FROM pgr_drivingdistance(
                 ''''SELECT id, source, target, time_4 as cost FROM jaen'''',
                 1, 15, false, false
         ) as dd
      ) as di
   ) as pp;`

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your comment. When i try to run it i get this error 'ERROR:  una cadena de caracteres entre comillas está inconclusa en o cerca de «'SELECT id, ST_X(the_geom) AS x, ST_Y(the_geom) AS y FROM ( SELECT id, seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost, the_geom FROM pgr_drivingdistance( ''''SELECT id, source, target, time_4 as cost FROM jaen'''', 1, 15, false, false ) as dd ) as di ) as pp;»
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM pgr_pointsaspolygon('SELECT id, ST_X(the_geom)...'.I tested closing the first SELECT into as pp but i get another error. Perhaps insert a braket at the end?.

Comment: I think you only need one set of '' around your query that is passed to pgr_drivingdistance?

Comment: I tried this to but about two days ago i found a theme related to [http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/52484C84.3000504@gmail.com]; adding four ' into pgr_drivingdistance SQL it works. I will try to change the SQL parameters.

Comment: Perhaps to get the correct result i should add something like `  JOIN jaen_vertices_pgr pt
  ON di.id1 = pt.id;` but using dd,di,pp

Comment: Solved. The problem was on the id and id1 format,i had configured id1 as bigint and it must be int.
Thanks John Barça for your code.